# Varied interest rate calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

Hey I am new to coding and was wondering if you guys could help me out with calculating different interest rates and then adding them to the next interest rate. So basically I'm trying to get interest rate A and adding it to the starting value of 100. then I want to get interest rate B for 100 and add that value to interest A. So far here is my code but I get 10 lines for each interest rate. Sorry if this sounds confusing but hopefully the code makes it more clear or maybe I could try to explain better if whoever reads this wants to. Thanks!!

```
int intv;

cout << " Accumulate interest on a savings account. ";
cout << " Starting value is $100 and interest rate is 1.25% ";

cout << endl;

intv = 100;
index = 1;

while ( index <= 10 )

{
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.25% for a total of " << .0125 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.27% for a total of " << .0127 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.28% for a total of " << .0128 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.30% for a total of " << .0130 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.31% for a total of " << .0131 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.32% for a total of " << .0132 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.35% for a total of " << .0135 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.36% for a total of " << .0136 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.38% for a total of " << .0138 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.40% for a total of " << .0140 * intv + intv << "." << endl;

    index = index + 1;

}
```

Instead of doing this for me I just want hints. I wanna fix this myself but am stuck as to what I have to do.

The desired out come of this is for the program to give me this:

Year 1 adds 1.25 for a total of 101.25
year 2 adds 1.27 for a total of 102.52
year 3 adds 1.28 for a total of 103.80
year 4 adds 1.30 for a total of 105.09
year 5 adds 1.31 for a total of 106.41
year 6 adds 1.33 for a total of 107.74
year 7 adds 1.35 for a total of 109.09
year 8 adds 1.36 for a total of 110.45
year 9 adds 1.38 for a total of 111.83
year 10 adds 1.40 for a total of 113.23

Total interest credited was 13.23

Comment: Add a few more tags to your question. I'm not sure what language this is, so that would be a helpful tag! ;-)

Comment: Sorry. Its in C++ and I am using Visual studio 2012

Comment: No prob! The tags just help you get more responses, because people like checking out questions that they have an expertise in.

Comment: If you give me an example of the output you want, I bet I could pretty much write the code for you. (Even though I don't know C++!)

Comment: Well we can help you solve any issues you have, but we aren't going to solve your homework for you. Give it a try and when you run into some errors edit your post

Comment: Yeah I really just want hints. I have tried doing this for 2 days but I keep confusing myself. I have finished all the other parts of my assignment but this part I can't seem to get.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use a `for` loop:

```
double rate = 0.125;

for (unsigned int index = 0; index < max_rates; ++index)
{
    cout << " Year " << index << " adds "
         << (rate * 100.0)
         << "% for a total of "
         << rate * intv + intv << "." << endl;
    rate += 0.002;
}
```

Comment: Alright it seems to work with just one interest rate. Is there a way to make it calculate different rates so that I don't have to have multiple copies of this code?

Comment: You could store the multiple values of interest in an array and use another for loop to repeat this for all the interests

Answer (score 0):

You need use a function to replace

```
cout << " Year " << index << " adds 1.25% for a total of " << .0125 * intv + intv << "." << endl;
```

The function can convert the index to adds value like

```
double foo(int index);
```

The input value is 'index', the output value is adds value like 1.25%, 1.38% .etc.

Then delete all cout lines. And just add this line:

```
cout << " Year " << index << " adds " << foo(index) * 100.0 << "% for a total of " << foo(index) * intv + intv << "." << endl;
```

I guess that is you want.

Comment: Alright it worked but I think I coded something wrong somewhere now because it says "Year 1 adds .000125% for a total of 101.25. Thanks all!!

Comment: Sorry, it has an error. Change ' foo(index) / 100.0' to ' foo(index) * 100.0'.